# Getting sum of all values of a specific unique name within groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I hope this makes sense, but I need to get the sum of values for a column but it needs to be all the values associated with one specific unique row value within the groups generated by groupby.

[image: Example data]

This is the code I used to group everything:

```
df_revPAR = df.groupby('IndustrySegmentName', as_index=False)[
    ['BrandRevenueTY', 'BrandSupplyTY', 'BrandDemandTY', 
     'IndustryRevenueTY', 'IndustrySupplyTY', 'IndustryDemandTY']].sum()
```

This does group the data based on "IndustrySegmentName" which I want and it gives me the sum of the brand data (each hotels day to day numbers). That is what I need for the brand data info.

Here's the problem. The industry data (IndustrySupplyTY, IndustryDemandTY, IndustryRevenueTY) repeats for different hotel names. The industry data is the same for the entire group (IndustrySegementName). That's not individual data like the "BrandSupply" or "BrandRevenue" data. I don't need to get a sum of all the rows of each different hotel within that group. I just need a sum of one of the hotel's industry data within the industry segment name group or I need to take that sum value I got from the above code and divide it by the number of unique hotel names that were grouped within each IndustrySegmentName. How do I do either of these?

For example, within the upscale group, I only need to get the sum of the "IndustryX" data from only Hotel Indigo to use as the "IndustryX" data for the whole "Upscale" group, not the combined sum of all the values within Hotel Indigo and Plaza Hotel.

Or I need to take the sum of "IndustryX" data within the "Upscale" group and divide it by 2 (number of unique hotels within this group), but I need a way to get this count.

Potential solution, but looking for a better way to code this:

```
df_brandcount = df.groupby('IndustrySegmentName', as_index=False)[
    ['Hotel Name']].nunique()
df_revPAR['BrandCount'] = df_brandcount['Hotel Name']
```

Comment: Do you need `df.groupby(['Hotel Name','IndustrySegmentName'], as_index=False).sum()` ?

Comment: I think I figured out a solution. I can use nunique to get a count of the hotel names within each segment group and divide the industry sums with that count number. This might be the easiest way to do this, at least for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be easiest method. Get the count and divide the total by it.

```
df_brandcount = df.groupby('IndustrySegmentName', as_index=False)[
    ['Hotel Name']].nunique()
df_revPAR['BrandCount'] = df_brandcount['Hotel Name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do two separate group by?

So one for the hotel specific data and one for the industry specific data. Afterwards you can then merge the data.

Untested code, as there is no test data sample provided:

```
df_hotel = df.groupby('IndustrySegmentName', as_index=False)[
    ['BrandRevenueTY', 'BrandSupplyTY', 'BrandDemandTY', 
     'IndustryRevenueTY', 'IndustrySupplyTY', 'IndustryDemandTY']].sum()
df_brand = df.groupby(['IndustrySegmentName','DateTY'], as_index=False)[
    ['IndustryRevenueTY', 'IndustrySupplyTY', 'IndustryDemandTY']].max().groupby('IndustrySegmentName', as_index=False)[
    ['IndustryRevenueTY', 'IndustrySupplyTY', 'IndustryDemandTY']].sum()

df_revPAR = pd.merge(df_brand, df_hotel, on='IndustrySegmentName')
```